# iOS - Does UIPasteboard persist across major OS upgrades?

Tags: iphone, ios, uipasteboard

I'm developing an app that uses a custom pasteboard for persisting information. I tried an OS upgrade from iOS 6 to iOS 6.1.4 (over the air) and everything was persisted just fine, but when upgrading to iOS 7 beta 1 (with iTunes), the pasteboard was deleted.

I'm wondering what happened. Could it be that UIPasteboard persists only when doing minor OS upgrades, or is it related to the fact that I upgraded with iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the fact that you upgraded with iTunes. Using the pasteboard to save information is a bad idea though. The information is not guaranteed to persist, and will be wiped out eventually. You should save the information to a file or use `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Agreed. The pasteboard should only be used as a temporary location strictly to be used to get data between apps. It is not designed to be any kind of persistent store.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it to share data with other apps. I would like for the data to persist as much as possible, event after upgrading the OS, but it's not a mandatory requirement (although it would be a neat feature for my use-case). Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in Apple's documentation about the persistence levels of UIPasteboard.